# Not able to parse JSON in ruby on rails using function JSON.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following function in my controller file where I have a string and I am trying to parse it using JSON.parse.
The problem I am facing is that I am not able to print the value of message which is present in the hash that is being returned.

```
def index
  .........  
  r = '{"response":"{\"message\":\"The following page was successfully Created 3035\",\"success\":\"0\",\"page_id\":\"3035\"}"}'
  @hash = JSON.parse(r)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  end    
end
```

In my view file I am using the following code

```
<%= @hash['response']['message'] %>
```

The output that I am getting is 
**message**
instead of getting 
**The following page was successfully Created 3035**

I have 'require json' on my controller file.

If I do

```
<%= @hash['response'] %>
```

Then I get the whole hash.Please help

Comment: From where did you get the `r` value ?

Comment: The r value is something which I want to check.The value of r would be dynamic but right now just to check how it will work I am assigning a string in JSON format.

Comment: But the JSON is invalid thats why its not working.Try with proper JSON

Comment: @shiva: yes you are correct..The JSON string was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string looks off. It basically contains a single key/value pair, with the key being `response` and the rest being a `String` containing what looks to be escaped JSON:

```
"{\"message\":\"The following page was successfully Created 3035\",\"success\":\"0\",\"page_id\":\"3035\"}"
```

In other words, the behavior you're seeing is to be expected given the input you're giving.

If you change the JSON input to (ie making sure the value in `response` isn't given as a JSON-encoded string):

```
r = '{"response":{"message":"The following page was successfully Created 3035","success":"0","page_id":"3035"}}'
```

I imagine it'll work like you expect.

The reason `@hash['response']['message']` is returning `"message"` is because `@hash['response']` is a `String`. Sending `[]` to a `String` with a `String` parameter results in the parameter `String` being returned if it occurs in the recipient `String`:

```
"foobar"["bar"] #=> "bar"
"foobar"["baz"] #=> nil
```

See [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have wrong JSON-string assigned to r.
The proper string should look like this:

```
"{\"response\":{\"message\":\"The following page was successfully Created 3035\",\"success\":\"0\",\"page_id\":\"3035\"}}"
```

In comparison to your version it does not have double quotes around response contents, so that `JSON.parse` returns you a hash with proper values you are expecting:

```
{"response"=>{"message"=>"The following page was successfully Created 3035", "success"=>"0", "page_id"=>"3035"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Hck for the answer . You mentioned it correctly but I found Jakob's answer more informative so I have accepted his answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def index
 r = '{"response":"{\"message\":\"The following page was successfully Created 3035\",\"success\":\"0\",\"page_id\":\"3035\"}"}'
 @hash = JSON.parse(r)
 @messagehash= JSON.parse(@hash['response')

 respond_to do |format|
    format.html
 end    
end
```

In your View:-

```
 <%= @messagehash['message'] %>
```